# Add data with Django data migration

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration, django-south

Is it possible to add, data do DB with South data migration in Django? I don't mean change of DB structure, I need to change the value of some fields. I know that it could be done via Django admin, but I need migration way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You need to use data migrations. With south, you can call

```
$ ./manage.py datamigration <app_name> <migration_name>
```

which will create a data migration file in your migrations module. You can then do your migration in `forwards(self, orm)` function. Just make sure that when accessing models, you use `orm`. For example, if I wanted to prefix every `User`'s username

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for user in orm.User.objects.all():
        user.username = 'prefix' + user.username
        user.save()
```

You can find more information in the [official tutorial](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html).

Comment: Thank you! That is what I am looking for.